# Remember me login - Asp script

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, authentication

hello
i have to create a "remeber me login" asp script, have read many scripts about this procedure and  have see that many people use to store username and password inside a cookie.
In my opinion it is not secure (safety), some advice

Comment: Why wouldn't this be safe using proper encryption?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the password. You only need the username and if you make sure that it is properly encrypted it is OK to save it in a cookie. It is important for the user to not be able tamper with the value and if he does the server should detect it. SHA1 for HMAC generation and AES for encryption are commonly used algorithms.

Comment: Including the username increases the risk, storing a cookie with an encrypted not easily identifiable piece of information like a GUID associated with the user record in the database is best.

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice NOT to store usernames and passwords in client side cookies. Store some kind of opaque reference instead that matches something in your server side authentication database.

Even better still encrypt this value before storing it in a cookie.

Comment: so i have to create a field on DB then compare this value with cookie if it matches is ok

Comment: Something like, try something like a GUID.

Answer (score -3):

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    StudentService.Service1Client studentCleint = new StudentService.Service1Client();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbnLogin.Text = studentCleint.login(txtusername.Text, txtPassword.Text);

        if (lbnLogin.Text == "Succesful")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Students.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            lbnLogin.Text = "failed";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how does that answer help in any way to the original question?

Comment: This isn't even [tag:asp-classic] so has no place in this question, thats before you consider the fact its completely ambiguous without any explanation.